# Given a fibonacci sequence where $f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2) for \space n\ge 2 $and $f(0)=0,f(1)=1$

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

***Prove that there exists four non-negative integers n for which $f(f(n))=f(n)$***

I tried to solve it by:

$f(f(n-1)+f(n-2))=f(n)$
Thus $f(n-1)+f(n-2)=n$(But I am confused at this)
Please give me atleast one hint to solve this problem.

[image]

For some users like @poetasis I directly post the snapshot of the original question from the book. Sorry this is not a homework assignment.It is a practice book for Math.

For curious readers and enthusiasts in Mathematics, I think I should let you know that Fibonacci was actually invented in India back in 450 BCE and was later identified and elaborated by Gopala in 11th century. Hence it is a matter of pride for me, being an Indian, to let you all know that like many other inventions, Fibonacci had its roots in India.

Comment: Please understand I cannot understand how to even approach this problem. Give me some answer/hint whatsoever please.

Comment: For large values of $n$, $f(f(n))$ is going to be much larger than $f(n)$, so just check small values of $n$ until you have found them all. For example, does $n=0$ work? How about $n=1$? etc

Comment: @MikeEarnest I already did that but I get only 3 non-negative integers. The previous question was to prove $f(n)<f(n+1)$. Which I have proved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

You can compute the first terms:

- $\color{blue}{f(0)=0}$
- $\color{blue}{f(1)=1}$
- $f(2)=1$
- $f(3)=2$
- $f(4)=3$
- $\color{blue}{f(5)=5}$
- $f(6)=8$

Then prove by induction that for $k \geq 6$, you have $$f(k)>k$$ so there is no others solutions.

---

To develop on the comments once you have found the **three** solutions to $f(k)=k$ (i.e $0,1,5$). You have to solve:
$$f(n) \in \{ 0,1,5 \}$$
which have **four** solutions ($\color{green}{0,1,2,5}$):

- $f(\color{green}0)=\color{blue}{0}$
- $f(\color{green}1)=\color{blue}{1}$
- $f(\color{green}2)=\color{blue}{1}$
- $f(3)=2$
- $f(4)=3$
- $f(\color{green}5)=\color{blue}{5}$
- $f(6)=8$

and for $n \geq 6$ you have $f(n) \geq 6$ so $f(n) \notin \{0,1,5\}$

Comment: I have done that already. But I get only three numbers, the questions demands 4 non-negative integers.

Comment: @Saradamani The question is mistaken.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by ‘solving’ but what the statement is saying is, for example, 5+3=8 where f(n)=8, f(n-1)=5, and f(n-2)=3. That’s what defines the fibonacci series: that each number is sum of the two numbers before it.

0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144…
Is this an assignment? If so, what does the assignment demand?

Comment: The question is not mistaken, @Saradamani is mistaken. There do exist four numbers $n$ for which $f(f(n)) = f(n)$.

Comment: No @poetasis it is a question asked in Indian Statistical Institute entrance test for either BMath/BStat. It is in the book called Test of Mathematics at The 10+2 level.

Comment: @Delta-u I still did not get by how you say "four solutions". Can you work it out please?

Comment: The idea is to work in to step:
* if $f(f(n))=f(n)$ then $k=f(n)$ is a solution of $f(k)=k$. Let $K=\{k, f(k)=k\}$.
* then you have to solve $f(n) \in K$.

Comment: @Delta-u Can this be passed on as a proof. I mean its existential but how to generalize this? Because they asked for a proof.(By they I mean the book. Please see my OP for some users I have directly taken a snapshot of that page)

Comment: Yes, the main point to carefully write out is that there is no solution for $n \geq 6$.